# How to filter child collection in JPQL query?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I've the following DB model:

```
Category -< ProductCategory >- Product -< Variant
```

(`Category` has many-to-many relationship with `Product` and `Product` has one-to-many relationship with `Variant`)

Now I need to get all `Category` records that have product with *active* variants. I'm getting these objects via the following JPQL query:

```
@Query("select distinct c from Category c join c.products as p join p.variants as pv where pv.active = true")
```

It works well - returns categories accurately - however every single `Category` contains *all* the products - **not only** these with **active** variants.

How can I filter out the products (or variants) that are inactive in a single query?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Opalo/0b404c41ffd75bdd2eb5a5026667d482)'s a postgres script that with database struct and sample data. For given data two categories (*CAT 1*, *CAT 2*), two products (*PROD 1*, *PROD 2*) and three variants (*VAR 1*, *VAR 2*, *VAR 3*) should be returned.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and it took me a while to find out how this works. The child list should be filtered when you add `FETCH` after your `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Category c JOIN FETCH c.products as p join p.variants as pv where pv.active = true
```

Comment: The way I see it, this approach is more a hack than actual tool, because it is unstable. If before executing this query we (in the same transaction) fetch some products (say P1 and P2) in normal way, they are fetched with their all corresponding variants, right? Say we then execute the query, and some category C1 contains P1 and P2. JPA will not re-fetch those products P1 and P2 again - because naturally that would overwrite already fetched P1 and P2 in EntityManager; it reuses P1 and P2 from EM. Ergo, C1.products will contain P1 and P2 with all their variants, not just active.

Comment: So, depending on what entities we fetched before executing the query, it might do or don't filter items as intended. I say that's not good enough.

Comment: I think that this answer works with the caveat mentioned by @MaksimGumerov

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on it, and I found that the FetchType in the @OneToMany annotation is important. It need to be set as Lazy mode. If it is Eager mode, jpa will create the sql query to fetch the data from the table for your child collection and won't filter it for you.

Comment: Amazing! That was it man. I spent a lot of time trying to understand what was wrong with my code. Thanks