# Spring data JPA derived query for multiple @OneToMany entities and inner entity localization

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to do a simple task with Spring Data JPA derived queries and am unable to get the desired results from the query. Basically I have a Book which can have one or many Chapters with localization support for the Book as well as the Chapter. I want to create a query which would fetch a language specific book (with chapters) based on the Locale. Here are my four entities.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Book {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private int noOfPages;

    /**
     * Both mappings below are unidirectional @OneToMany
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private List<BookTranslation> bookTranslations;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private List<Chapter> chapters;

    /**
     * Constructor for JPA
     */
    protected Book() {
    }

    public Book(int noOfPages, List<BookTranslation> bookTranslations, List<Chapter> chapters) {
        this.noOfPages = noOfPages;
        this.bookTranslations = bookTranslations;
        this.chapters = chapters;
    }
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class BookTranslation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Language language;

    private String name;

    /**
     * Constructor for JPA
     */
    protected BookTranslation() {
    }

    public BookTranslation(Language language, String name) {
        this.language = language;
        this.name = name;
    }
}


@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Chapter {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private int chapterNumber;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CHAPTER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private List<ChapterTranslation> chapterTranslations;

    /**
     * Constructor for JPA
     */
    protected Chapter() {
    }

    public Chapter(int chapterNumber, List<ChapterTranslation> chapterTranslations) {
        this.chapterNumber = chapterNumber;
        this.chapterTranslations = chapterTranslations;
    }
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ChapterTranslation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Language language;

    private String title;

    /**
     * Constructor for JPA
     */
    protected ChapterTranslation() {
    }

    public ChapterTranslation(Language language, String title) {
        this.language = language;
        this.title = title;
    }
}

public enum Language {
    EN, FR
}
```

Below is the sample code, I am using to persist these entities. Ignore the @GetMapping please, this is just a sample.

```
    @GetMapping("/persist-book")
    public void persistBook() {
        ChapterTranslation enChapter = new ChapterTranslation(Language.EN, "What is Java persistence?");
        ChapterTranslation frChapter = new ChapterTranslation(Language.FR, "Qu'est-ce que la persistance Java?");
        List<ChapterTranslation> chapterOneTranslation = new ArrayList<>();
        chapterOneTranslation.add(enChapter);
        chapterOneTranslation.add(frChapter);
        Chapter chapterOne = new Chapter(1, chapterOneTranslation);
        List<Chapter> chapters = new ArrayList<>();
        chapters.add(chapterOne);

        BookTranslation enBook = new BookTranslation(Language.EN, "JPA WikiBook in English");
        BookTranslation frBook = new BookTranslation(Language.FR, "JPA WikiBook in French");
        List<BookTranslation> bookTranslations = new ArrayList<>();
        bookTranslations.add(enBook);
        bookTranslations.add(frBook);
        Book book = new Book(500, bookTranslations, chapters);
        bookRepository.save(book);
    }
```

My BookRepository looks as follows:

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {

    List<Book> findBooksByBookTranslations_LanguageAndChapters_ChapterTranslations_Language(Language lang1, Language lang2);
}
```

Sample code I am using to retrieve the result.

```
@GetMapping("/english-book")
    public List<Book> retrieveEnglishBook() {
        return bookRepository.findBooksByBookTranslations_LanguageAndChapters_ChapterTranslations_Language(
                Language.EN, Language.EN
        );
    }
```

My expected output is as attached in the image below.

[image]

One thing that I noticed from the Hibernate logs is that Hibernate makes a total of four select queries and the first query output is exactly what I need. However, since this a method name based query I don't suppose I can control that.

**EDIT 1:** Before trying out the answer, I was getting all books with all their locales returned, after changing my query to the one given in the accepted answer I was able to get the Book with the selected locale.

Please note: I also had to change all collections from using a List to a Set, more on this can be read about in the accepted answers link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe as a desired result is a single database result. 
I guess what you mean by that is you expect to get all the books but only with the translations in a single language.

You don't describe what you actually get, so assume you are getting the book with all available translations.

Your desired result is beyond the capabilities of derived queries. 
The different predicates of a derived queries all limit the root entities to be returned `Book` in your case. They should still have all references in tact.

You could achieve your goal with an annotated query like this:

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT b FROM Book b 
        JOIN FETCH b.bookTranslations as bt
        JOIN FETCH b.chapter as c
        JOIN FETCH c.chapterTranslation as ct
        WHERE bt.language = :lang   
        AND ct.language = :lang")
    List<Book> findBooksByLanguage(Language lang);
}
```

See also [How to filter child collection in JPQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847016/how-to-filter-child-collection-in-jpql-query)

Side note: query derivation should only be used when the resulting method name is VERY similar to what you would have named the method anyway.